# Real-time data from Raspberry Pi to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, websocket, real-time, raspberry-pi2

I recently have not much experiance about working with a raspberry.
I need to send real-time data from my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B to an iPhone. The Raspberry will get the internet connection via UMTS stick. 
I thought about a websocket but I didn't find any information what websocket would be the best and how to config it.
So is there anyone who already has a solution about it?

Thank you!

Comment: Websocket is a technology implemented for the browsers. For your application, you can use [socket.io](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/) to create a socket server in raspi and connect to it using iOS. Or you can write a custom server and the connect to it through [socket streams](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html).

Answer (score 2):

WebSocket requires a WebSocket (WS) server or a webserver that understands the WebSocket protocol as defined by the IETF.  So for a RPi to talk *directly* to your iPhone, one of the devices has to have a WS server... which is not likely.

There are a couple of possible alternatives (there are certainly others).  You could send data from the RPi to an external server that hosts a WS-capable server which then forwards that data to your iPhone, either thru a native app or a web browser.  The data is logically transmitted between the two devices, but physically sent using an external service to coordinate the two.  Visit http://goo.gl/Utg0dU to see data exchanged between an RPi and an iPhone using web messaging (src available).

Another possible alternative is to use Bluetooth to send data *directly* from the RPi to the iPhone.  Being a Java dude, I know you can run a JVM on the RPI and I know there's a Java bluetooth API, and obviously the iPhone supports bluetooth, so its definitely do-able with a JVM.  A quick Google shows plenty of support for bluetooth on the RPi with other languages.  So you're good with this approach too.

Comment: Your goo.gl link gives a 404 now.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Unfortunately I no longer have control of that website since I changed companies.  You might want to check out Google's Firebase for real-time web messaging.

Answer (score 1):

If the Raspberry Pi is connected to the Internet with a public IP Address (I guess it doesn't since it uses UMTS) then you can setup a TCP Listener where the iPhone will connect to. If it doesn't and you can do Port Forwarding (I guess you can't) then you can forward the TCP port to the Raspberry Pi. The above examples also work with an HTTP server.

If the iPhone is near the Raspberry Pi and you're writing an app for the iPhone you can use a Bluetooth transceiver on the Pi to communicate.

If you can't do any of this you may need a third server with a public IP where both devices will connect to and the server will relay all connections from one device to the other.

In general, it would help if you could describe a little bit better what you want to achieve and the network topology involved so we can provide more specific answers.